# Neutral (grounded conductor) for bathroom switch (NEC 404.2(C))?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom

I understand that a grounded conductor (neutral) is not required by code (404.2(C)) for bathroom switches, but is there any reason that I would want to include it - future-proofing, etc.?

I'm going to rewire my bathroom soon (fan with light, vanity, and one GFCI outlet).  The home run is in the ceiling, so I'd have to run a traveler to the switches in the walls if I want a neutral at that location.

Comment: Where do you see that bathroom switches are excluded from this requirement?

Comment: @Tester101 I'm using Mullin & Simmons' "Electrical Wiring Residential, 18th ed."  They quote 404.2(C), Item 2, which states one exception for the requirement for grounded neutrals as "where the switch does not serve a habitable room or bathroom."  They follow up this quote with a table stating bathrooms don't need the grounded neutral.  My question stems from the fact that 404.2(C) is extremely poorly worded.  The reader is being asked to address more exceptions to the rule than actual implementations, hence my wish to clarify if I need the neutral in my switch leg or not.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree the wording is poor, but I believe "*Where the switch does not serve a habital room or bathroom*" means in a place other than a habitable room or a bathroom. So the neutral **is** required in a bathroom.

Comment: @Tester101 Yeah, that's exactly how I initially interpreted that sentence, too (neutral required), but the book contradicts that interpretation - in other words, the book interprets Item 2 as being read as if it were two separate clauses: the case  "where the switch does not serve a habitable room" and the case "where the switch does not serve a bathroom."  Again, adding up the double-negatives would mean that one doesn't need the grounded neutral - per the book's interpretation - in any bathroom switch.

Comment: I think the book's interpretation is incorrect. The NEC does not consider a bathroom to be a "*habitable*" room, as evidenced by ***210.70 (A)(1) Habitable Rooms** At least one wall switch controlled lighting outlet shall be installed in every habitable room and bathroom.*.  Notice that a bathroom is **not** a habitable room.  So in the text you're referencing, they have to include the bathroom as a separate item.  So if the switch is in an area that is not a habitable room or a bathroom (e.g. a garage), then a neutral is not required.

Comment: The only reason to run a neutral would be to, as you said, future-proof. Timer switches, motion sensing (IR) switches need a neutral, and likely future specialty electronics. I have found that neutrals in switch boxes often cause problems when lay persons start fiddling around.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- that's only because switch loops were wired with 14/2 and a retagged white wire to begin with ;)  Had I had my dibs, neutrals at switch boxes would have been Code for a long time by now -- retagged white wires bite people on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is faulty -- 404.2(C) may not have required neutrals at bathroom light switches at one point in time, but it certainly does in the current (2014) NEC!

> **C) Switches Controlling Lighting Loads.** The grounded circuit conductor for 
>   the controlled lighting circuit shall be provided at the location where switches 
>   control lighting loads that are supplied by a grounded general-purpose branch 
>   circuit for other than the following:
>
> (4) Where a switch does not serve a habitable room or bathroom